# Counting the number of times a symbol is printed on tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter interface that prints statements beginning with various symbols (e.g. asterisk) using the text widget.

I would like to know if it is possible to count the number of times a certain symbol appears on the text widget and then display that number on the text widget as well. The code that I have used to print the text is fairly basic and is shown below. Any form of help would be appreciated.

```
Text.insert('end',"* Error detected!")
```

Comment: See string [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

Comment: Ok thanks, I should have read the documentation,